# MS Graph API: Wrong file size in DriveItem info

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a Word file that has a **sensitivity label** set. When fetching this file info using:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
```

I get the following response:

```
  "@odata.context": *",
  "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "*",
  "createdDateTime": "2020-11-23T14:34:46Z",
  "eTag": "\"{57B2B6AB-CA5B-4404-B714-69D4ACF1BAD2},10\"",
  "id": "*",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-11-23T14:35:42Z",
  "name": "Document.docx",
  "webUrl": "*",
  "cTag": "*",
  "size": 36298,
  "createdBy": *,
  "lastModifiedBy": *
  },
  "parentReference": *,
  "file": {
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "hashes": {
      "quickXorHash": "KxC7GCjPid2b5o3NGboS9vBPhKg="
    }
  },
  "fileSystemInfo": {
    "createdDateTime": "2020-11-23T14:34:46Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-11-23T14:35:42Z"
  }
```

As you can see the size of the file is **36298**. However, if I download the file using the link from **@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl** I can see that the file size is bigger. Looking at the content-length header in the response the file size is **59392**. I see this behavior only with files that have sensitivity labels set. Is that something expected to happen or it's is bug in MS Graph?

Comment: Whenever you upload a new item into Onedrive, it adds more info with it (like its metadata info, versioning, labeling info, incase applied etc); i think due to that only you will see the above differences.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: there is no such problem with other type of files (like png, pdf...). For now, I only see this problem with doc files that have a sensitivity label set

Comment: Looks like design to me, as i said its related to metadata info/versioning/labeling etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected to happen with Office files if label you applied also aplies encryption. This is applicable to Office files only (and maybe PDFs).

File size you see is original file size, but the actual content is encrypted so the actual file size is different.